# Bootloader Install Failed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my SONY VPCEL15EN, Every thing worked fine but at the end it shows that Bootloader Install Failed. Now I have 3 options 
1 to install somewhere else 
2 continue without a Bootloader > Manually Install a bootloader
3 Quit Installation 
Now i want to know how to manually install a Bootloader ?

Comment: Try selecting the second option and insert the Live CD and try to install the BootLoader.

Answer (score 0):

1st option : get a disk including Boot-Repair
The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to create a disk containing the tool (eg Boot-Repair-Disk, a disk starting Boot-Repair automatically), and boot on it.

Remark : it is recommended to install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer). Do not burn it on a DVD if your computer has Windows8 pre-installed, or if your boot is in EFI mode.

2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu
- either from an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
Using Boot-Repair
Recommended repair
launch Boot-Repair from either :
the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.
Warning: the default settings are the ones used by the "Recommended Repair". Changing them may worsen your problem. Don't modify them before creating a BootInfo URL, and asking for advice on Ubuntu Forums Absolute Beginners Section or in Installation and Upgrades.